# What will happen if I delete branch that I merged into another branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch

The case is that I opened a branches (b1) that I merged into another one, develop this one and then I want to merge it into master. What will happen if I delete b1? Will I lost in b2 all committed changes done in b1? Situation depicted below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `b1` is merged into `b2`, there's no ongoing link, it's just that the same commits that were in `b1` have been copied into `b2`. Deleting `b1` won't have any effect on the commits that are also now in `b2` — **if** `b1` is really merged into `b2`.